# IDA Pro sp-analysis failed

Tags: disassembly, c#

I'm trying to reverse engineer a C# file that requires a password to continue running. When I load it in IDA Pro I get nothing in the functions window and a sp-analysis failed

[What I see when loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C18tp.png)

Comment: for the record I'm new to this so sorry if I'm just stupid

Comment: You probably want dotPeek or similar for C#, not IDA. It's compiled to an intermediate language, not assembler, and with plenty of metadata included so is much simpler to decompile.

Comment: when I try in reflector I just get errors about no metadata

Comment: Why do you think it’s C#?

Comment: first use `De4Dot` on the C# file to clean it up, then use `.NET Reflector` or `JustDecompile` on it

Answer (score 3):

If this is C# (or any other .NET file) you need to use a tools such as .NET reflector to "decompile" it into .NET intermediate language.

Anyhow...

The error you are seeing means that at the end of a function the stack pointer (typically the ESP register) does not point to the address expected by the function type, for example: it may have `PUSH`ed something on the stack and did not `POP` it by the end of the function.

This warning does not stop analysis, but you should be aware of the situation when `JMP`ing between addresses.

Tip:

In general settings you can choose the "show stack pointer" options and see the state of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

about `analysis failed`, you can refer official doc:

[analysis failed](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/failures.shtml#11)

maybe can find the solution to fix it.

my case is `Decompilation failure: xxx call analysis failed`, and refer it to find out solution.

For more detail pls refer [another post's answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15473/why-is-ida-call-analysis-failing/30542#30542)